# TimeOut connection to symfony.com via http proxy

Tags: php, symfony, curl, proxy, windows-10

New job, new problems:)

I would like to write a new Webapp in PHP using Symfony. My PC runs Windows 10 and all HTTP-Requests have to go via a proxy running Squid.

Accessing the web and downloading files via Browser (eg. IE) works fine, but the connection to the Internet is quite slow.

So I imported all my proxysetting from IE to Windows by

> netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie

Now if I want to create a new Symfony app by

> php symfony.phar new hellosymf

I only get

> [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException]   cURL error 7: Failed to
>   connect to symfony.com port 80: Timed out

Any idea how to fix this? Can I increase the timeout-value?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update you composer and recreate your application  ?

Comment: No. If I try to dl composer with
' php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php

I only get

' readfile(http://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream.

Seems to be the same problem :(